# Host sencha touch 2 on heroku

Tags: heroku, sencha-touch-2, host

Is it possible to host a sencha touch 2 wep app on Heroku?

I know, Heroku does not have Sencha in library list, but maybe I can use Node.js or something else to push the app.

I really appreciate if you know a solution or an example/instruction how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution as well, which works pretty well for me:

1. Created an express project based on NodeJs
2. Use router for pointing to the sencha files
3. Deploy on heroku as a node.js https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs
4. Beside the heroku hosting gain even NodeJs advantage , pretty much having JS as a server side and client side language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's definitely possible, I already tried two options, both worked for me.

1. You could use Node.js, then you simply have to [write a web server](https://github.com/odi86/kort/blob/34cc2e6446ffe6de68c6ee5b57aae16991b3319e/server.js) to serve your static content.
2. Probably the easiest solution is to create an `index.php` file and let heroku detect your app as PHP. This gives you an Apache web server that you can use for your Sencha Touch app.

Hope this helps.